# admin-ajax.php won't load without logging as admin- JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

Tags: ajax, cache

Has anyone here run into this error before? I have a WordPress webpage and I'm trying to load a map (OpenStreetMap) with lots of markers (geojson). It works fine if I'm logged in as admin but it doesn't work when I'm not logged in.
It's throwing errors such as:
JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF
Error loading settings (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.callback'))
Error retrieving marker list (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'o.length'))

I think this error has to do with admin-ajax.php being called. My website is hosted on a shred host of Godaddy managed WordPress (with cache/Cloudflare), GoDaddy refused to disable cache because it's a shared host. So I'm looking for a different solution from WordPress community. Hope someone here knows how to fix it. Any suggestion is much appreciated.
Thank you!
Julian

Comment: Just an idea, but did you added both priv and nopriv actions to the Ajax call? Without more context, it might be you are not doing the action for logged-out users.

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test-action', 'test-action');`
`add_action('wp_ajax_test-action', 'test-action');`

Comment: Hi Alex, yes indeed.
add_action('wp_ajax_mmp_map_markers', array($this, 'map_markers'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mmp_map_markers', array($this, 'map_markers'));
add_action('wp_ajax_mmp_map_geojson', array($this, 'map_geojson'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mmp_map_geojson', array($this, 'map_geojson'));
add_action('wp_ajax_mmp_map_marker_list', array($this, 'map_marker_list'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mmp_map_marker_list', array($this, 'map_marker_list'));